# Date ranges into one row by ID with no gaps

Tags: sql-server

I am reviewing reports that contain date ranges by a member ID and upload date. This looks like the following:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|     UploadDate     |     MemberID        |     StartDate       |     EndDate        |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     08/01/2020     |    12345            |     04/01/2020      |    10/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     08/01/2020     |    12345            |     01/01/2020      |    03/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     06/01/2020     |    12345            |     01/01/2020      |    03/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     06/01/2020     |    98765            |     02/01/2020      |    03/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     06/01/2020     |    98765            |     05/01/2020      |    08/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     07/01/2020     |    34568            |     01/01/2020      |    12/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     07/01/2020     |    34568            |     03/31/2020      |    06/01/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to merge rows with the same UploadDate and the same MemberID where their are no gaps in the date range StartDate - EndDate. If there are gaps the rows will not be merged.

The expected output would be:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
|     UploadDate     |     MemberID        |     StartDate       |     EndDate        |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     08/01/2020     |    12345            |     01/01/2020      |    10/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     06/01/2020     |    12345            |     01/01/2020      |    03/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     06/01/2020     |    98765            |     02/01/2020      |    03/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     06/01/2020     |    98765            |     05/01/2020      |    08/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     07/01/2020     |    34568            |     01/01/2020      |    12/31/2020      |
|                    |                     |                     |                    |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

I had been trying the following without success:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [MemberID],[StartDate],[EndDate]) AS RN,
    [MemberID],
    [StartDate],
    [EndDate],
    LAG([EndDate],1) OVER (ORDER BY [MemberID],[StartDate], [EndDate]) AS PreviousEndDate
FROM
[dbo].[RCNI]

SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN Groups.PreviousEndDate >= [StartDate] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IslandStartInd,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Groups.PreviousEndDate >= [StartDate] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Groups.RN) AS IslandId
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [UploadDate], [MemberID],[StartDate], [Benefit End Date]) AS RN,
        [UploadDate],
        [MemberID],
        [StartDate],
        [EndDate],
        LAG([EndDate],1) OVER (ORDER BY [UploadDate],[MemberID],[StartDate], [EndDate]) AS PreviousEndDate
    FROM
        [dbo].[RCNI]
) Groups
```

Comment: For `MemberId=12345` you have a row with `EndDate=2020-12-31` in your expected result, where does that date come from? Any chance of a typo?

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I think the tireless nights from a newborn is to blame or at least I can use it as an excuse. Lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below appears to work for the given sample data. In words with would be something like:

1. Filter out rows that have a period that falls completely within another row for the same `UploadDate` and `MemberId` (the `not exists` clause in the common table expression `cte`).
2. Look at the remaining rows for each `UploadDate` and `MemberId` combination (`over(partition by r.UploadDate, r.MemberId ...`) and sort them by `StartDate` (`... order by r.StartDate)`).
3. If the start date of a row comes before, is equal to or comes one day after the end date of the previous row for the combination (`lag(r.EndDate) over(partition by r.UploadDate, r.MemberId order by r.StartDate)`), then they must be merged.
4. If rows must be merged, then the start dates becomes the smallest start date of the combination (`min(r.StartDate) over(partition by r.UploadDate, r.MemberId)`). All rows that must be merged now have the same start date (`StartDateNew`).
5. Determine the new end date by grouping on `UploadDate`, `MemberId` and `StartDateNew` and taking the maximum value for `EndDate`.

**Sample data**

```
create table rcni
(
  UploadDate date,
  MemberId int,
  StartDate date,
  EndDate date
);

insert into rcni (UploadDate, MemberId, StartDate, EndDate) values
('08/01/2020', 12345, '04/01/2020', '10/31/2020'),
('08/01/2020', 12345, '01/01/2020', '03/31/2020'),
('06/01/2020', 12345, '01/01/2020', '03/31/2020'),
('06/01/2020', 98765, '02/01/2020', '03/31/2020'),
('06/01/2020', 98765, '05/01/2020', '08/31/2020'),
('07/01/2020', 34568, '01/01/2020', '12/31/2020'),
('07/01/2020', 34568, '03/31/2020', '06/01/2020');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as
(
  select r.UploadDate,
         r.MemberId,
         case
           when r.StartDate <= dateadd(dd, 1, lag(r.EndDate) over(partition by r.UploadDate, r.MemberId order by r.StartDate))
           then min(r.StartDate) over(partition by r.UploadDate, r.MemberId)
           else r.StartDate
         end as StartDateNew,
         r.EndDate
  from rcni r
  where not exists ( select 'x'
                     from rcni r2
                     where r2.UploadDate = r.UploadDate
                       and r2.MemberId = r.MemberId
                       and r2.StartDate < r.StartDate
                       and r2.EndDate > r.EndDate )
)
select c.UploadDate,
       c.MemberId,
       c.StartDateNew,
       max(c.EndDate) as EndDateNew
from cte c
group by c.UploadDate,
         c.MemberId,
         c.StartDateNew;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=367a06fb8377c1ac26d434dbb6bafe20)